# font rendering on chrome v safari .. how does this site do it?

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari

hi been trying to find a solution for to make fonts look as nice as they do in safari 5.1.7
in chrome v34

in chrome (and IE and FF) they are all jagged, but in safari they are nice and crisp!!

heres example
chrome
http://screencast.com/t/CpJDoManNbQg

safari
http://screencast.com/t/9nYGOh7N

if you dont notice this aliasing difference between the major browsers or think its worth complaining about then pls dont reply

why dont all browsers have the same font rendering as safari?!
its so much nicer and easier to read!
its 2014 for goodness sake!

so as  designers we can produce websites that look like printed material

anyway!

i stumbled across this site just before
and on chrome the text appears very close to how it does on safari
eg there is way more anti aliasing than before

http://action.sumofus.org/a/Facebook-app-taps-phones/3/2/?sub=fb

EDIT here another site with clean anti aliased fonts on chrome!
https://www.dartlang.org/

can someone tell me how its been done?

or how else to smooth the jaggys?

ive trawled here trying everything and nothing seems to work!

thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 2):

Chrome has a problem with rendering fonts, even those from Google Fonts.

One way I've found is adding this to your css:

```
-webkit-text-stroke: 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
```

As you can see more here:

http://www.dev-metal.com/fix-ugly-font-rendering-google-chrome/

Comment: * Assuming your text color is black (0, 0, 0)

Comment: thanks this one did have some effect
although i changed it to
-webkit-text-stroke: 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
was too heavy and noticeable otherwise...



still not as clean as this site manages for example?
https://www.dartlang.org/

Comment: hmm just checked safari, now there are issues there

besides , looking for a solution across the board, not per class

Comment: Yes, the '0.1' is for opacity, from 0 to 1. What happened in Safari? You can put this into the body tag in your css, to change the whole site.

Comment: About darlang.org, here in my Chrome (35.0.1916.114m) the biggest texts are pretty rough, while the smallest ones are almost unreadable. Using FF or even IE they render well.

Take a look in this screenshot, with normal zoom: http://www.screencast.com/t/xsCJO6qtar

And here, the same window with 110% of zoom: http://www.screencast.com/t/X5wqrAsAfcco

Comment: hmm herein lies the conundrum i guess, get it good in one browser and it looks poor in another... just find it strange with all the resources they cant get this right between all browers...

see same site in my chrome v 35 
http://screencast.com/t/YvyLYSn7c

i just updated chrome and i think fonts are a little smoother after this update

Comment: Hey Kym! I suppose you're still looking for a good fix for this. Well, yesterday I found a blog which explains how to fix the font bug. Actually, all you need to do is use your font as SVG. Take a look: http://www.adtrak.co.uk/blog/font-face-chrome-rendering/

Comment: Again, good news! The new 37th version of Google Chrome has increased the font rendering. Now it looks like other browsers. Update yours and give it a try :D

Answer (score 0):

It seems more like one is bold, or different weight- safari being heavier. I see this all the time, usually i test the difference between ie/ff/chrome  sometimes to compensate i add a few more font weights with cufon and make ie lighter.

Comment: in my screenshots im using fontface not cufon
im trying to find a solution taht doesnt involve font replacement?

Answer (score 0):

One thing I always add to my class for better font rendering is this.

-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;

Try it out and see if there is any improvement.

Comment: have tried this
dont see any difference at all with this